# Constructor instantiation in a world of guaranteed copy elision

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Consider this example:

```
template <typename T>
using type = typename T::type;

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    A(type<T>);
};

A<int> f();
A<int> g() { return f(); }
```

Neither gcc nor clang compile this code due to `int` not having a nested `type` typedef. But why is that constructor being instantiated at all? `f()` is a prvalue of the same type as the return of `g()`, there shouldn't even be a move there. What is causing us to instantiate the bad constructor?

Comment: Copy elision elides only the actual copy itself. The code still must meet all the rules that it would normally need to meet if copy elision did not occur. The code gets compiled as-if no copy-elision took place, but the copy itself gets elided.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is not true.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: He's talking about guaranteed elision, which does not have such requirements. There *is no copy* to be elided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constructor is a bit of a red herring. The same would happen if it was any other member function.

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void foo(type<T>); // Same error
};
```

This is on account of [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2)

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the
>   definitions, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class
>   member functions, [...]

The declaration is instantiated, so `type<T>` has to be well-formed.