# With guaranteed copy elision, why does the class need to be fully defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

A followup to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044566/constructor-instantiation-in-a-world-of-guaranteed-copy-elision). Consider the following:

```
class C;
C foo();
```

That is a pair of valid declarations. `C` doesn't need to be fully defined when merely declaring a function. But if we were to add the following function:

```
class C;
C foo();
inline C bar() { return foo(); }
```

Then suddenly `C` needs to be a fully defined type. But with guaranteed copy elision, none of its members are required. There's no copying or even a move, the value is initialized elsewhere, and destroyed only in the context of the caller (to `bar`).

So why? What in the standard prohibits it?

Comment: Haven't you put the compiler in a position where it needs to know sizeof (C) in order to invoke `foo()`?  Even if the copy / move is elided, the results of invoking `foo()` have to go _somewhere_.

Comment: @PaulSanders Isn't this the answer?

Comment: The question is now [opinion-based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/5376789). But you can easily edit it to make it more clear as suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5376789).

Comment: Right. I feel I should apologize to any interested parties. I did want the letter of the law as written. Apologies to anyone who refrained from answering because it seemed opinion based. Thank you all for your points about the rationale! That's invaluable too.

Comment: @xskxzr Not really.  I think both Walter and I were just trying to be polite in our phraseology.  Nonetheless, you have navigated your way to the relevant passage in the standard (funky green highlighting and all :)

Comment: I have been reading this discussion for a few days already and I'm curious to understand exactly what you meant in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058119/with-guaranteed-copy-elision-why-does-the-class-need-to-be-fully-defined/51059420#comment89118701_51063152) of yours to @Paul Sanders. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on this a bit. Thanks. (read the next to follow)

Comment: I'm trying to understand specifically these two statements in the alluded comment: 1) "no size needed except in two places". What are those two places? 2) "Why we even need the size in between, is explained in the answer by @hvd" Which point is the one you called "in between"? How was that explained in the OP's answer? Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: @Belloc - The two places I thought of at the time were the call site of `bar` and the body of `foo`. The "in between" is the body of `bar`. I originally didn't understand why the body of `bar` needed to see how `C` is defined. My comment there may be misleading. It's not just *the size* of `C` that's required, but the information of whether `C` is trivial. Because without that information the body of `bar` can't know ABI to use. Does it need to pass in a pointer to the storage that gets initialized? Or is everything returned in registers, no pointer needed. That's what I understood there. HTH.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guaranteed copy elision has exceptions, for compatibility reasons and/or efficiency. Trivially copyable types may be copied even where copy elision would otherwise be guaranteed. You're right that if this doesn't apply, then the compiler would be able to generate correct code without knowing any details of `C`, not even its size. But the compiler does need to know if this applies, and for that, it still needs the type to be complete.

According to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.temporary :

> **15.2 Temporary objects [class.temporary]**
>
> 1 Temporary objects are created
>
> [...]
>
> (1.2) -- when needed by the implementation to pass or return an object of trivially-copyable type (see below), and
>
> [...]
>
> 3 When an object of class type `X` is passed to or returned from a function, if each copy constructor, move constructor, and destructor of `X` is either trivial or deleted, and `X` has at least one non-deleted copy or move constructor, implementations are permitted to create a temporary object to hold the function parameter or result object. The temporary object is constructed from the function argument or return value, respectively, and the function's parameter or return object is initialized as if by using the non-deleted trivial constructor to copy the temporary (even if that constructor is inaccessible or would not be selected by overload resolution to perform a copy or move of the object). [ *Note:* This latitude is granted to allow objects of class type to be passed to or returned from functions in registers. -- *end note* ]

Comment: Some friendly links with funky green highlighting: [1.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#1.2) and [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#3). (I love this guy's site).

Comment: Every time I come back to this, I realise you managed to get right to the heart of this in the minimum possible number of words.  Nice, please ignore some of my earlier, rather naive, comments.

Comment: "You're right that if this doesn't apply, then the compiler would be able to generate correct code without knowing any details of C." This is clearly wrong and doesn't make any sense to me. The accepted answer by @xskxzr is very clear about this (-1).

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with copy ellision. the `foo` is supposed to return a `C` value. As long as you just pass a reference or pointer to `foo`, it's OK. Once you try to call `foo` - as is the case in `bar`- the size of its arguments and return value must be at hand; the only valid way to know that is presenting a full declaration of the requiered type.
Had the signature been using a reference or a pointer, all the  required info was present and you could do without the full type declaration. This approach has a name: pimpl==Pointer to IMPLementaion, and it is widely used as a means of hiding details in closed-source library distros.

Comment: Damn your eyes Red Wave!  I was just about to say that!  The accepted answer is the right one; it depresses me that the most upvoted answer got so any votes, it's not relevant at all.  And the compiler needs to know sizeof (C), mainly, unless it needs to copy the result of calling `foo()` for some reason (but with RVO it wouldn't).

Comment: @PaulSanders - The high voted answer is very relevant. Copying a trivial type is a bitwise copy. As the note indicates, this is to facilitate returning stuff in registers. Well, to know if the type can be simply returned in a register, we need to know its size (does it fit in a register). We actually don't need to know the size otherwise. Copy elision is usually done by passing a hidden pointer where the result would be written, no size needed except in two places. *Why we even need the size inbetween*, is explained in the answer by **@hvd**.

Comment: @StoryTeller None of that matters, in the contex of the original question.  If, for example, a hidden pointer is passed to `foo()` to give it somewhere to store its result, the caller still needs to know how much memory to allocate on the stack to accommodate said result.  You got away with declaring `foo()` as returning `C` because the compiler, at that stage, _didn't_ need to know that.

Comment: @PaulSanders - `bar` doesn't need to allocate any memory for the result of `foo`. It just forwards the hidden pointer it was given itself when it was called. That's the whole point of copy elision.

Comment: I think that's asking a lot of the compiler.  See @xskxzr's answer.  And copy elision is just an optimisation.  The compiler is faced with compiling `bar()` and `bar()` called `foo()` with class `C` not fully defined, and that is illegal.  Also, this is actually RVO, no?

Comment: @PaulSanders - You do know copy elision was made *mandatory* in C++17, right? Poor choice of words, since nothing is ever there to be elided under the new model, but there you have it. The only exception is in the answer you disparaged.

Comment: @PaulSanders accepted answer is the short technical wording. Mine is just a simple clarification on why it should be so.

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't, and I see now where you're coming from, but that code is illegal for the reason given in the accepted answer.  OK, technically, the compiler has enough information to compile `bar()`, but it's not wise for it to try.  Suppose we now call `bar()` with `C` still incompletely defined, and so on?  Much better, for the programmer's sanity, to report a piece of code that _clearly contravenes the standard_ straightaway.  Interesting discussion, this.

Comment: @RedWave In the general case, yes, the above discussion notwithstanding.

Comment: @PaulSanders - The paragraph in the accepted answer gives the mechanics (what I wanted to know). The quotes in the other answer give the exception and the rationale (what everybody *should* know). If (and that's a big if) that exception didn't exist, and all class object were returned the same way, then my code sample could be legal. The compiler needs the complete object type to determine how to deal with the return value, since it still has options. And yes, the size is one of the things it needs to know for that purpose. But otherwise it doesn't need the size in general.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean (and size is probably _all_ it needs to know, if copy elision is guaranteed).  **@hvd**, I take it all back.  I think, in general, doing _anything_ with an incompletely defined type (other than using it as a pointer or to declare the return type of a function or method) is likely to remain off-limits.  It just makes no sense for the compiler to try, there's no value in it.

Comment: Is there anything in the standard specfying the details of copy elision implementation? I can see that It could be done in such a way that the outermost caller of a sequence of return chain is responsible for the house keeping,  but I am not sure if that is the only - or even the best - implementation. Implementation is closely related to platform. what if the object is supposed to fit within registers? how about RISC architectures? The assumed implementation might suit the strict stack-based platforms; not general enough IMHO.

Comment: Storing objects that are not trivially movable/copyable in registers would open up a massive can of worms because you have to be able to pass a reference to the objects to be moved/copied to the move/copy constructor and that move/copy constructor can pass those references onwards to anywhere it likes.

Comment: @plugwash not necessarily. you do not always need to pass the reference. and keeping objects in registers a common practice; specially in RISC architectures.

Answer (score 6):

The rule lies in [[basic.lval]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#9):

> Unless otherwise indicated ([dcl.type.simple]), a prvalue shall always have complete type or the void type; ...

Comment: I think the question is *Is this rule really needed?* (in this context)

Comment: @Walter Yes it is, see Red Wave's contribution for a concrete reason.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the number of answers and amount of commentary posted to this thread (which has answered all of *my* personal questions), I have decided to post an answer 'for the rest of us'.  I didn't initially understand what the OP was getting at but now I do, so I thought I'd share.  If you know all this and it bores you, dear reader, then please just move on.

@xskxzr and @hvd effectively answered the question, but @hvd's post especially is in standardese and assumes that readers know how return-by-value (and by extension [RVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)) works, which I imagine not everybody does.  I thought I did, but I was missing an important detail (which, when you think it through, is actually pretty obvious, but still, I missed it).

So this post mainly focuses on that, so that we can all see why (a) the OP wondered why there was an issue compiling `bar()` in the first place, and then (b) subsequently realised the reason.

So, let's look at that code again.  Given this (which is legal, even with an incompletely defined type):

```
class C;
C foo();
```

Why can't the compiler compile this (I have removed the `inline` because it is irrelevant):

```
C bar() { return foo(); }
```

The error message from gcc being:

> error: return type 'class C' is incomplete

Well, first up, the accepted answer quotes the relevant paragraph from the standard that explicitly forbids it, so no mystery there.  But the OP (and indeed commenter Walter, who picked up on this straightaway) wanted to know why.

Well at first that seemed to me to be obvious: space needs to be allocated for the function result by the caller and it doesn't know how big the object is so the compiler is in a quandry.  But I was missing a trick, and *that* lies in the way return-by-value works.

Now for those that don't know, returning class objects by value works by the caller allocating space for the returned object on the stack and passing a pointer to it as a hidden parameter to the function being called, which then constructs the object, manipulates it, whatever.

**However**, this daisy-chains, so if we have the following code (where we fully define `C` before calling `bar()`):

```
class C
{
public:
    int x;
};

C c = bar ();
c.x = 4;
```

then space for `c` is allocated *before* `bar()` is called and the address of `c` is then passed as a hidden parameter to `bar()`, and then passed directly on to `foo()`, which finally fills constructs the object in the desired location.  So, because `bar()` didn't actually *do* anything with this pointer (apart from pass it around) then all it cares about is the pointer itself, and not what it points to.

Or does it?  Well, actually, yes, it does.

When returning a class object by value, small objects are usually returned in a register (or a pair of registers) as an optimisation.  The compiler can get away with doing this in the majority of cases where the object is small enough (more on that in a moment).

But now, *`bar()` needs to know whether this is what `foo()` is going to do*, and to do that it needs, for various reasons, to see the full declaration of the class.

So, in summary, that's why the compiler needs a fully-defined type in order to call `foo()`, else it won't know what `foo`() will be expecting and so it doesn't know what code to generate.  Not on most platforms anyway, end of story.

**Notes:**

1. I looked at gcc and there are seem to be two (entirely logical) rules for determining whether a class object is returned in a register or pair of registers:

   - a) The object is 16 bytes or smaller (in a 64 bit build).
   - b) [`std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) evaluates to `true` (maybe someone can find something in the standard about that).
2. In case any readers don't know, RVO relies on **constructing** the object *in its final resting place* (i.e. in the location allocated by the caller).  This is because there are objects (such as some implementations of `std::basic_string`, I believe) that are sensitive to being moved around in memory so you can't just construct them somewhere convenient to you and then `memcpy` them somewhere else.
3. If constructing the returned object in that final location is not possible (because of the way you coded the function returning the object), then RVO doesn't happen (how can it?), see live demo below (`make_no_RVO()`).
4. As a specific example of point 1b, if a small object contains data members that (might) point either to itself or to any of its data members, then returning it by value will get you into trouble if you don't declare it properly.  Just adding an empty copy constructor will do, since then it is no longer trivially copyable.  But then I guess that's true in general, don't hide important information from the compiler.

Live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8REeWpn5nYGu6H0k).  All comments on this post welcome, I will answer them to the best of my ability.